# Sort Values in DAX/Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have a dynamic graph title that will change based on what time component is selected (Period[Period]) and by the shifts that are selected (T_HISSSHIFTS[C_PERIOD]).

The values in T_HISSSHIFTS[C_PERIOD] are showing up out of order e.g. D,B,C,A. I need it to come out as A,B,C,D or in order of what is selected. Below is the code, any ideas how to order these shifts?

```
    Title_Eff+MachineType = 
"Knit Effeciency by "
    & CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( Period[Period] ), Period[Period], ", " ) & " By Shifts "
    & CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( T_HISSHIFTS[C_PERIOD] ), T_HISSHIFTS[C_PERIOD], ", " )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the order easily:

```
CONCATENATEX ( <Table>, <Expression> [, <Delimiter>] [, <OrderBy_Expression> [, [<Order>] [, <OrderBy_Expression> [, [<Order>] [, … ] ] ] ] ] )
```

So changing your code to:

```
  Title_Eff+MachineType = 
"Knit Effeciency by "
    & CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( Period[Period] ), Period[Period], ", " ) & " By Shifts "
    & CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( T_HISSHIFTS[C_PERIOD] ), T_HISSHIFTS[C_PERIOD], ", " , T_HISSHIFTS[C_PERIOD])
```

Should give you the expected output.

Comment: Perfect, I need to get into the habit of looking at the base equation more carefully. Nothing fancy needed, just an order by. Thank you!!